# Connect GoLang to GitHub

Tags: go, github

I have a fairly large project in github that I would like not to download in its entirety. The file is mostly Go based. Unfortunately, most of the file's packages call each other. I would like to use some of the files within this repo to test my code before I push it with the rest. Is their any way to import it into golang without downloading the file (using go get github.com/foo)?

As stated above, I've tried using go get github.com/etc. but it's way to large for that.

Comment: Shouldn't you use a package manager like dep?

Comment: Why is it "too large"? Too large for what, specifically? Does the download timeout? Is it using too much disk space? How large is it?

Answer (score 1):

There's no tool I know of that could do this. You could use `go list -f '{{ .Imports }}'` or similar to list the dependencies you need for any given Go package, and script a way to download only the files needed. But you also have to think about things like templates or config files that your programs might access too.

Alternatively, and I have no idea if this will work, you could try mounting your Git repository as a FUSE mount. I [found this](https://www.presslabs.org/gitfs/) in a quick Google search. This will let you download the files you need on demand, and of course when you compile your program, it will only include the code needed.